# Valores de registros de uma tabela relacionada concatenados na consulta da entidade principal

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas: ordem_servico e ordem_servico_tecnicos.
Caso exija mais de uma técnico para um O.S., são criados registros de cada técnico na segunda tabela relacionados pelo numero da ordem(id).

Gostaria de fazer um consulta das ordens abertas que mostrasse os técnicos relacionados a ela.

```
    SELECT
     os.numero_os AS numero_os
    FROM
    ordem_servico os
    WHERE
    os.data_servico BETWEEN '$data_cad_i' AND '$data_cad_f'
```

Com subquery deu o erro: "Subquery returns more than 1 row" porque realmente tem mais de um tecnico para a mesma O.S..

Comment: Não é só fazer um `INNER JOIN`? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join

Comment: Não dá. Imagine que a ondem 1234 tenha os técnicos A e B, então na tabela de **ordem_servico_tecnicos** havera dois registros, um para cada técnico. O que eu gostaria é de ter uma linha de retorno da consulta da ordem de serviço com o nome dos dois técnicos que vão execulta-la.

Comment: Rafael, você diz na mesma linha? Sem repetir a ordem?

Comment: Isso, os tecnicos aparecerem na mesma linha dos dados da OS em um campo apenas, como se estivessem concatenados.

Comment: Procure entender sobre functions, elas podem resolver seu problema.

Comment: Corrigi minha resposta na tentativa de te ajudar. Veja lá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a função [`group_concact`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) você poderá concatenar na mesma coluna todos os registros da sua tabela de técnicos agrupando-os por `id` e `nome`.

Observe que a sub-consulta na tabela filha com essa função.

```
select os.numero_os as numero_os,
    (select group_concat(`nome` separator ',') as `tecnicos`
     from  (select id_servico,
                   concat(`nome`, ':', group_concat(`Value` separator ',')) as `nome`
            from ordem_servico_tecnicos
            group by id_servico, `nome`) tbl
     where tbl.id_servico = os.id_servico) as tecnicos
from ordem_servico os
where os.data_servico between '$data_cad_i' and '$data_cad_f'
```

Comment: Obrigado Ismael. Mas com isso, se eu tiver 3 técnicos na mesma O.S., a consulta vai me retornar 3 linhas, o que eu gostaria é ter uma unica linha e um campo com o nome dos 3 tecnicos que foram indicadas para o serviço.

Comment: Sua pergunta não tinha sido clara a ponto de entender que não era apenas um inner join. Vou refazer a resposta para não ter que remove-la.

Comment: Valeu... a função group_concact resolveu.